# Count fails with aggregate function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a query like the following:

```
Author.select('authors.*, max(books.published_at) as last_publishing')
  .joins(:books)
  .group('authors.id')
```

This does what I want (returns a list of authors annotated with their most recent publishing date), but if I try to call count on this query, there is an issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(authors.*, max(books.published_at) as last_publishing) 
AS count_authors_all_max_books_published_at_as_last_publishing, authors.id 
AS authors_id FROM "authors"
INNER JOIN "books"
ON "books"."author_id" = "authors"."id"
GROUP BY authors.id

*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...COUNT(authors.*, max(books.published_at) as last_pu...
```

Obviously this is not the SQL I want to generate - I just want a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( ) myQuery.

I saw there was [a similar issue with Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13648) - has anyone else come up against this/is there a workaround?  I can do query.to_a.size, but I would prefer to just be able to use the count method for my, and my coworkers, future sanity.

Comment: You can't use count in this case as you are using a custom select. If the records have been loaded you can use `.size` or `.length` instead.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `.select(...)` part?

Comment: @MarcRohloff Yes, it works if I remove the select and group by, because it's just a generic query at that point.  However, I obviously need the aggregate information, and I don't want to bring all those extra records into memory needlessly.

Comment: If you call `Author.joins(:books).group('authors.id')` you should get a count of all authors who have books, which is what it looks like you are trying to do. It won't pull all the records into memory.

Comment: @MarcRohloff No, that's not what I wanted to do.  I was trying to get a list of all authors annotated with the date of the last book they had published.  I also needed to be able to count the number of records returned for pagination reasons, which was throwing the error.  It seems like you can't do it with a custom select and an aggregate query.

Comment: I assume the first query you posted works for the first part that you needed. Unfortunately you can't do a count using the same query. Are you using a pagination gem? If so which one?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove select temporary before call count

```
authors = Author.select('authors.*, max(books.published_at) as last_publishing')
      .joins(:books)
      .group('authors.id')
    total_authors = authors.except([:includes]).count(:all)
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this case that wasn't an option, because count was appended to the query by Kaminari iirc.